# Configuring p4 on Solaris

Tags: solaris, perforce

I'm trying to configure p4 (Perforce) on Solaris, but have had no success. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

**Reference:**
http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4guide/02_config.html#1073398 - "Using Config files"

1. User specific env variable `P4CONFIG=.p4settings`
2. `.p4settings` file under Client root
3. Client root: `$HOME/client_root/`
4. .p4settings contains p4user, p4port, p4host and p4client

If I run the following:

```
p4 info
```

**Expected result:**

```
User name: ...
Client name: ...
...
..
```

**Observed result:**

```
Perforce client error:
        Connect to server failed; check $P4PORT.
        TCP connect to perforce failed.
        perforce: host unknown.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out myself!

It was with the way I set the environment variable in the *.profile* file.

**Correct:**

```
export P4CONFIG=.p4settings
```

**Incorrect:**

```
P4CONFIG=.p4settings
```

The official documentation on the Solaris website doesn't mention anything about having to use "export".

[docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/806-7612/customize-8/index.html](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/806-7612/customize-8/index.html)